# how to use LIKE and % with pymssql on an undetermined number of parameters?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pymssql

I am using pymssql to connect to a database.
That database has a table that has a column (let's call it col) on witch all the strings are 64 chars long. (ex: `"John                                                                "`).
Now i want to find John in the database. i tried using `LIKE`.
When i hardcode the name it works perfectly :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE 'John%' ") // gives perfect results
```

But when i try it using `%s` this seems to match nothing.

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%s%' ",(0,"John")) // gives Nothing
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%s%' ",{0:"John"}) // gives SQL "Incorrect syntax" error
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%s%' " % {0:"John"}) // gives unsupported format error
```

If i wanted to match only one column this would have worked :

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%s%' ", "John") // gives all Johns
```

But I want to match on an undetermined number of columns.
Is there a way to have a look a what the final query would look like so I can try debugging it myself. Or else do you know how to use many parameters.
after looking [here](http://pymssql.org/en/latest/pymssql_examples.html) it seems I should use an array of tuples but i can't find a way to make it work.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE %s ", "John%")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would write this using `format()`, if I were being lazy"

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '{0}%' ".format("John") )
```

Or more correctly using parameters:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table WHERE col LIKE '%s%' ", ("John"))
```

I think the issue is that `(0, "John")` is interpreted as two parameters, not one.

Comment: Downvote for proposing SQL injection vulnerability.